# How to use custom lambda name instead of autogenerated one when deploying with zappa?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda, zappa

I have existing lambdas deployed to **AWS** and chose **Zappa** for further lambda deployments. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be a way of customising  lambda name, I found nothing similar on their configuration docs. It would be a real pain to start using Zappa's forced naming convention *project_name-env* since there are multiple apps using these lambdas and as you already guessed I would need to update these apps separately to use new names so thats not an option. Any suggestions for the best approach?